# What language is used in select attributes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with the following bit of code that I can't grasp, specifically the stuff within the `select=` sections. I don't know how to break it down (I'm assuming there's a better way to format it) and can't tell how the pieces are interacting.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="field[@key = 'household_live'][@prompt != current()/prompt[@key = 'household_live'][text() = 'Parent 1']/@id][@prompt != current()/prompt[@key = 'household_live'][text() = 'Parent 2']/@id]">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="concat(parent::*/field[@key = fw:replace(current()/@key, 'live', 'first')][@order = current()/@order]/text(), ' ', parent::*/field[@key = fw:replace(current()/@key, 'live', 'last')][@order = current()/@order]/text())" />
    <xsl:for-each select="parent::application">
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `@` is or how the brackets are interacting. The `\` also confuses me, since I'm guessing it's not dividing anything.

Essentially, what language and what syntax am I working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language is XPath. XPath is a language specifically for navigating the structure of an XML document, @ symbol means attribute, / symbol is used as path specifier, sort of like files in a file system, except its nodes in an XML document. 
XPath comes with all sorts of functions as well like position(), concat(), etc Axes specifiers like parent:: etc.

XPath works tightly with XSLT. Its pretty much the way the XSLT document access the XML document it is reading.

Just google XPath for more info.

MDN Tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)

Comment: Thanks!! The word 'XPath' is all I needed. Googling pieces of the code wasn't bringing up even that much.

Comment: @Ray: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped you the most.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's **[XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)**.

XPath is a wonderfully expressive standard for selecting parts of an XML document.  XSLT depends upon it heavily.  You must learn it for XSLT, but its usefulness transcends XSLT: it's used in XML Schema, and many other languages have XPath libraries.  It's essential anywhere parts of an XML document must be selected, including testing XML, web page scraping, and other applications.

**XPath is to XML as regular expressions are to text.**

Highly recommended addition to your toolbox.